# C: How do I edit a line in an existing text file?

Tags: c

Im attempting to create a program that replaces 1 line in a text file, if that line matches a specific pattern, with a new line. I've been looking at some simple functions but none of them does what I want (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm). I guess that I could create a new textfile and write the lines that needs to be changed to that file and copy the lines over that needs to remain the same but I could imagine it would be easier having 1 file.

So here is my question, is it possible to replace one line with another in an existing file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not easier having a single file, it's basically impossible.

Text files on disk do not support inserting data in the middle, or deleting data. You can thus only replace the line with a new one of the *exact* same length, which is not generally very useful.

You should do it as a filter, i.e. read the input, write to a new output, and write the new line instead of the old when you detect that you're at the proper position.

Comment: If you really want to do it "in-place", you'd need to read the whole file, replace the line, and then overwrite the original file with your changed buffer.