# Find the specified string in txt file and subtract the same value from the number

Tags: c, file, edit

**Goal**: I use language C in Visual Studio 2022 to reduce the serial number by 7252 after “STORAGE_” in the file located at *C:/Users/13383/Desktop/storage.txt*. The data in *storage.txt* is as the following figure:

```
...

"STORAGE_7253":
...
"STORAGE_7254":
...
"STORAGE_7255":
...
```

**Already done:** my program as shown:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1000

int main() {
    FILE* fp;
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    char* pos;
    int num;

    if (fopen_s(&fp, "C:/Users/13383/Desktop/storage.txt", "r+") != 0) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, fp) != NULL) {
        pos = strstr(line, "STORAGE_");
        if (pos != NULL) {
            num = atoi(pos + strlen("STORAGE_"));
            printf("%d\n", num);
            num -= 7252;
            sprintf_s(pos + strlen("STORAGE_"), MAX_LINE_LENGTH - (pos - line) - strlen("STORAGE_"), "%d\"", num);
            puts(line);
        }
        //fputs(line, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("Done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Problem:** When I comment out the `fputs(line, fp);`, I found the variable "line" contents the correct thing:

[image: terminal picture]

But when I uncommented "fputs" to write the strings in document, it prompted an error:

[image]

So I want to know what's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: You must do a seek-like operation on the file stream when switching from reading to writing and when switching from writing to reading.  And you'd need to seek backwards to overwrite what you just read. I see no seeking operations.  `fseek(fps, SEEK_CUR, 0)` is a no-op seek that might be useful after writing.

Comment: Note: the Python code reads the entire file, seeks to the beginning of the file, the re-writes the entire contents - modifying as it goes.

Comment: The fundamental issue you are trying to solve is an "in-place" text substitution in a file.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270388/c-how-do-i-edit-a-line-in-an-existing-text-file?rq=3

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest fix:

Open "storage.txt" file read only - we'll call it ifile

Open "new.storage.txt" file for output - we'll call it ofile

Enter read loop from ifile

```
Read line from ifile
Process line
Write line to ofile
```

Close ifile

Close ofile

If new ofile created successfully, rename ifile to "yyyyMMddhhmmss.storage.txt" (where "yyyyMMddhhmmss" represents a datetime)

Rename ofile to "storage.txt"

It's always best to nondestructively update files, so writing a new file, then renaming the old file and renaming the new file is the prudent approach. If something goes wrong during file I/O operations, no harm, no foul.